# Wireguard server on Raspberry pi no longer 'forwarding' to the rest of the network

Tags: networking, raspberry-pi, wireguard

Looking for some help with Wireguard server on Raspberry Pi, as it appears to have stopped working as it used to.

My setup is a home network with a static external IP address, and a 192.168.2.0/24 internal address space.

I have a Wireguard server running on a raspberry pi, and this had been working fine, to allow me to setup connect to my home network from outside, and the RDP to a Windows 10 machine on the network.

However things seem to have changed ! While I can still connect to the server and setup the tunnel, I cannot RDP tp the windows machine (or in fact ping any other machine on the network). I can however SSH into the Wireguard server and ping everything from there.

It as if the packets are not getting past that one machine.

Any help appreciated, before I attempt a rebuild of the wireguard server

Comment: Do your other machines have a route back to the Wireguard IP address range? (Either routes directly on the machines, or routes on your home router.) Or does your Wireguard configuration enable iptables SNAT to avoid the need for that?

Comment: Frankly I have no idea regarding that as I had simply installed pivpn on the pi using one of the guides. How would I know if those routes exist or not ? or how would I set them up if required, My router is an ISP supplied TPLink Deco X58 (X50 for ISPs)